# Example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that U is closed under addition and is closed under scalar multiplication but is not a subspace of R2

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

I think in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the only solution to this question would be the empty subset, but how do I define addition and multiplication for it?

If i have $\emptyset+\emptyset$ does it equal $\emptyset$ ?
And if i do $a\cdot\emptyset$ does it equal $\emptyset$ ?

Would there be another example for the original question?

Comment: Yes, it is the only solution. And you don't have to define the addition and the multiplication by a scalar, since the only function from the empty set into the empty set (or any other set, for that matter) is the empty function.

Comment: If $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is your subset, the assumptions say $S$ contains the span of every $s \in S$. By taking one vector at a time, you could show $S$ is the span of some vectors (so a subspace). You're right, in any vector space, a set that's closed under addition and multiplication will be a subspace as soon as it's not empty.

Comment: Empty sets cannot be linear spaces,  so the answer is not.

Comment: You don't have to add the empty set to itself or multiply it by a scalar. "Closed under addition and scalar multiplication" means you can add any two **elements** of the empty set and you can multiply any **element** of the empty set by any scalar. And both of those are (vacuously) true.